# OSX, VMWare Fusion: how to map function keys for a Windows Server 2003 VM

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to map the function keys on a mac keyboard for a VM running MS Server 2003 under VMWare Fusion on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VMWare Fusion 2 you can map the keys once you have the VMWare Tools installed on Windows Server 2003. I used this up until about 3 months ago and never had a problem mapping any of the keys. VMWare Fusion does this better then Parrallels, unfortunatly the way they do Coherance does not work well for me.